# Why text with lower font size increase tr height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having a strange issue, in [this page](http://globalize.herokuapp.com/articles/4) there are two spans with different font-size.

[image: Screenshot]

The first span (with content "With empty title") has no explicit font size thus it inherits a font-size of 100%, in css inspector it becomes 12px. The second span with the word 'EMPTY', is initially hidden and is viewable by clicking on IT flag. It has this css applied

```
td {
  .empty {
    color: #bbb;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  }
}
```

According to inspector, when "EMPTY" span is shown its computed size is 9px, however when the second span is shown there is a 1px flickering for the containing tr, on my browser tr height changes from 32px to 33px with the higher value when empty span is shown.

Why is this happening? How to prevent that without changing `span.empty` font-size?

Comment: apply `line-height:0.8em;` to the `<tr>`

Comment: @Banana even if it works that would decrease the whole tr height and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Your span is an inline-box , as much as a letter. it stands on the baseline and remains under it average 0.2em as any letters or inline-block does by defaut :). it increase height needed by span. so vertical-align top or bottom can erase that gap. so is line-height as Banana suggested

Comment: @GCyrillus I did not fully understood your answer, I'm not a css expert, however I fixed it with this css `span.field-translation.empty { vertical-align: bottom; }`. If you post it as answer (maybe with an explanation) I'll accept it.

Comment: Okay, i made an answer, hope it helps you to understand what's going on there :)

Comment: here is a codepen to play around with vertical-align or line-height http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rmxpo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span is an `inline` element and behave in the flow like letters or inline-boxes does.

It stands on the `baseline`, beneath the `baseline` , you have a gap that remains for letters such as : g,j,p,q,y,....

Letters and inline-boxes stands on `baseline` wich is the defaut `vertical-align` for any inline element. reset it to `vertical-align:top` or `bottom` and the gap will be part of area used.

If you reduce line-height, the baseline is reduced, and element 'too high' will be go over it.

*Hope it's clear enough, do not hesitate to edit this post to turn it into proper english , thks (erasable line)*